# Bad Syntax with let in LISP

Tags: recursion, lisp, let

I keep getting this error when trying to run the code:

```
(let ((exp lambda (x y) (if (= y 1) x (* (exp x (- y 1)) x)))))
```

Error:

```
let: bad syntax in: (let ((exp lambda (x y) (if (= y 1) x (* (exp x (- y 1)) x)))))
```

My function is supposed to define recursive exponentiation, but I'm having problems with let.

Comment: @RainerJoswig The presence of the phrase "bad syntax" in the error message is pretty much a dead giveaway of Scheme being in use. :-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: true, but which one? I would prefer not to guess what is being used, but get this information as part of the question. For example does he struggle with some kind of 'named let'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing an opening parenthesis before the `lambda`, and the `let` form is missing a body. Also, you can't use `let` for defining recursive functions; you need to use `letrec` (for Scheme) or `labels` (for Common Lisp). Perhaps you meant this (Scheme):

```
(letrec ((exp (lambda (x y)
                (if (= y 1) x
                    (* (exp x (- y 1)) x)))))
  exp)
```